InDesign reposition and transform objects
I am working on a long document in InDesign CS6 with a text frame on each page. I would like to do the following find and replace routines.

find each text frame of size [a1 x b1] and change it to size  [a2 x b2]

find each text frame with coordinates [x1, y1] and change to [x2, y2]


In the find string I would also like to specify "any" i.e. "any size" or "any coordinates"
I believe in newer versions of InDesign the object style settings has "Size and Position Options" but I am using CS6.
I would be grateful for any help with the script as the user interface does not give the option.
